# Web API - Handling the long running call when aggregating the calls

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a web api project which works as a GateWay for other Mobile clients. When the mobile client makes a call to this Gateway it internally calls the existing services which are hosted by another project and it aggregates the results and return to the client. I have recently come across a situation when my gateway is internally making 3 calls first 2 are returning the data fast but the 3rd call is taking lot of time I want to know the best way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to explain how your question is programming related. That means add relevent code or tags for programming languages. In any case I think that might belong to the server fault or super user board. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the return type of API action methods is `async Task<YourModelDataType>`. 
For example, let's say you have a `HomeController` controller as follows:

`public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        public async Task<YourModelDataType> Index()
        {
            return new YourModelDataType()
            {
                Property1 = await ApiService1.GetData(),
                Property2 = await ApiService2.GetData(),
                Property3 = await ApiService3.GetData(),
            };
        }
    }`

Ensure that calls to the other API projects are awaited. This improves *scalability* on the server side. i.e. server resources are free to serve other requests while awaiting response from other API services.